# How can I split a string about time into separate variables (hr, min, sec) in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, variables

I'm using selenium to scrape a website with constantly updating alerts, and the duration section looks like '37s' or '20m 11s' or '1h 14m 45s'.  The website updates 15 seconds or so, so the duration is always changing (unless the alert cleared, then it disappears completely.)

I'd like to create a way to be notified if an alert lasts longer than x amount of time, so I'd like to split up the time element and convert each piece into seconds.

I've tried `re.sub`, `re.split`, and others to try and separate the sections.  If it can be done within a single variable, that would be great.

```py
# The Chrome frame you need to be in to access the web elements for the alerts.
browser.switch_to.frame('maincontentframe')          

# This variable contains the information contained in the 'duration' web element(s).  
durationElem = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='servicetable']//tr[starts-with(@class, 'servicerow')]//div[starts-with(@class, 'duration')]")         

# This loop allows you to see each alert's duration.
for elem in durationElem:  
    minutes, seconds = elem.text.split("m,s")
```

I'd like to have some variables that contain just integers.  For example, if there's an alert that says '4m 10s', there would be two variables that contain 240 & 10.  Or even just one variable containing 250 would work.

Answer (score 0):

Well it appears the format you have provided has a space delimiter and can be separated at such.

`4hr 26min 30sec` can be our example input

```py
def findTotalSeconds(strInput):
    splitData = strInput.split(' ') # [4hr, 26min, 30sec]

    # Reverse the order (you will see why in a second)
    splitData.reverse() # [30sec, 26min, 4hr]

    # Isolate the integers
    parsedInts = []
    for parsedVal in splitData:
        parsedInts.append(int(''.join([s for s in parsedVal if s.isdigit()])))

    # parsedInts = [30, 26, 4]

    # Now you can mathematically convert the elements accordingly
    totalTime = 0
    for i in range(len(parsedInts)):
        totalTime += parsedInts[i] * (60 ** i)

    return totalTime
```

This logic for collecting the total time is as follows for our example `4hr 26min 30sec`

Generated splitData list: `['4hr', '26min', '30sec']`

Reversed: `['30sec', '26min', '4hr']`

Running through totalTime loop: `(30 * (60 ** 0)) + (26 * (60 ** 1)) + (4 * (60 ** 2))`

Running through totalTime result: `30 + 1560 + 14400 = 15990 total seconds`

Answer (score 0):

```
def seconds(line):
    D = {word[-1]:int(word[:-1]) for word in line.split()}
    return D.get("h",0)*60*60+D.get("m",0)*60+D.get("s",0)
```

Comment: You should include a description explaining your code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming elem.text holds a text string like "1h 3m 17s" or "10m", this should do what you want

```
import re
scale = {'h': 60*60, 'm': 60, 's': 1}
regex = re.compile("(\d+)([mhs])")

for elem in durationElem:
    seconds = 0
    for match in regex.finditer(elem.text):
        groups = match.groups()
        seconds += int(groups[0]) * scale[groups[1]]
    print(seconds)
```